# How to find the location of the mouse in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, mouse

I am making an image editor (just a simple editor for a program I am making), and I need to find the position of the mouse. Is it possible to do this in Objective-C? If so, how?

EDIT: I just thought I should mention that I have done some research on this and I haven't found anything that works. The code I have in my header file is as follows:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface test : NSWindow <NSWindowDelegate> {

}

@end
```

I can handle any outlets and actions that are needed; I just need to know how to find the position of the mouse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are catching it through an event, such as `mouseDown`, it will look like this:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    NSPoint mouseDownPos = [theEvent locationInWindow];
}
```

Otherwise, use:

```
[NSEvent mouseLocation];
```

EDIT: (Sorry, I wrote `NSPoint *`, which is wrong, since it's a struct)

Comment: The debugger keeps saying "Incompatible types in initialization", or "Incompatible types in assignment" if I separate the lines (so I initialize, then set, instead setting while initializing).

Comment: Oops, I accidentally put in NSPoint*. Try it again with the updated code.

Comment: Now it says "Invalid initializer". This is kinda confusing. EDIT: It works now (somehow), but when I click the mouse it shows (gbd) in blue and the application stops working.

Comment: Some more information would be useful, try adding a smart breakpoint for objc_exception_throw and see if you can trace the origin of the exception (if that's what it is).

Comment: Ok. It is suddenly working perfectly. I don't even remember changing the code. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Inside a mouse event handler (`mouseDown:`, `mouseUp:`, `mouseMoved:`, etc.), you can ask the event for its `locationInWindow`. If you need the mouse location at some arbitrary time (generally you won't want to do that, since it's rare for a program to have a one-off need to discover the mouse location), you can do `[NSEvent mouseLocation]` and it will return the mouse's location at the time in screen coordinates.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the coordinates from the origin of the view itself, use:

```
NSPoint locationInView = [self convertPoint:[theEvent locationInWindow] fromView:nil];
```

You can use this NSPoint directly to draw in the NSView coordinates; otherwise  with

```
[theEvent locationInWindow]
```

you will have the coordinates of the mouse in the window, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks this helped a lot. Here's the Swift 3 syntax for anyone needing that: `let locationInView = self.convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)`